# Case when with SUM not working as I want it to

Tags: sql

I'm trying to sum bit values for 2 specific statuses (4 and 16). Problem is, is that it isn't summing the bit values, but is instead keeping the value at '1'. So it is returning 'True' for each individual status, but it should sum the values from both statuses and only return True if it is equal to 2.

I want to return True if the of both values from status (4 and 16) = 2

I've tried subselects with IIF, count and sum.

```
CASE
    WHEN (status in ('4', '16') and sum(cast(bitvalue as int)) = '2') THEN 
    'True' ELSE 'False' end as 'test'
```

Should return true only when combined values from the statusesis equal to 2

Comment: Show us a complete query. And also sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text, not images. Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve before you start.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (IIF is a product specific function - but for which product?)

Answer (score 0):

Try below, by adding one more case for bitvalue, make sure you have group by statement

```
CASE
WHEN (status in ('4', '16') and sum(cast(bitvalue as int)) = '2') THEN 
'True' ELSE 'False' end as 'YourTestColumn',
CASE 
WHEN (status in ('4', '16') and sum(CASE WHEN bitvalue =1 then 1 else 0 end) = '2') THEN 
True' ELSE 'False' end as 'MyTestColumn'
```

Comment: Does not work unfortunately. If I change the '2' you've added for a 1, I get True for the individual statuses, so it doesn't combine to 2.

Comment: Try now i have added one more column just copy paste, should work.

Comment: Same result as before, both columns represent the same values

Comment: I've fixed it with a subselect. Thanks for your help